# Android app that imports a series of locations (lat, long) and notifies you when near it

Tags: android, gps, notification, geo-location

I wish to be notified on my Android phone when I get within a certain distance (few hundred m to a km, user adjustable) of a list of locations (imported in lat, long format; about 10..50 entries). Is there an app for this?

Comment: Yes there is, I stumbled about one a couple of weeks ago. Unfortunately I don't remember which it was, as I had no need for it. On a quick glance: Maybe [MagicContext](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.lostincontext) can be "abused" for that? It's not the one I had in mind, but the only one that I could find (on a quick check).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[BwareArea](https://f-droid.org/packages/fr.byped.bwarearea/)** might be what you are looking for. From the app's description:

> You'll import a POI list and it'll start an always-on-top widget displaying the closest POI and alerting you if you don't follow the POI requirements. All the parameters are configurable; minimal distance to warn, allowed over-speed, whether to automatically start when your car's Bluetooth is connected, or to log your track.

Seems to fit your requirements exactly. Works on Android 4.4 (Kitkat) and up.

Comment: the app is crashing on my Android 10 device, is there any alternative you can recommend?

Comment: @Dary The app hasn't been updated since then, and Android 10 wasn't there at that time. Maybe [report to the dev](https://github.com/X-Ryl669/BwareArea/issues) so they can fix it? Apart from that, maybe my lists have a fitting alternative – see [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationalert). IIRC, some [navigation apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_navigation) also offer such features, e.g. OsmAnd.